# How to set up paths and directories so that Zurb Foundation works with Django?

Tags: django, windows-7, sass, zurb-foundation

I followed this nice set of [instructions for setting up Ruby, Compass, and Sass](http://www.bigjason.com/blog/using-sass-django) on my Windows 7 system, except that I also installed Foundation 3 and didn't bother with rvm. Compass and Sass are working on the "zurbtest" Django project I set up (after working around some Compass quirks).

However, Sass is not able to compile app.scss. I get the message:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
              Load paths:
                c:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/zurbtest
                c:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/zurbtest/static
        on line 1 of static/zurbstyle/sass/_settings.scss
        from line 2 of static/zurbstyle/sass/app.scss
```

Looks like I need to point out the path where _ratios.scss and other zurb foundation files reside. I can see that they are on my Windows system, at:

c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-3.2.3/scss/foundation/common

But where do I need to specify that path to make this work?

I see that this issue has been discussed before in the context of Rails. I don't have Rails installed. This is a Django project.

So where and how do I set up the needed paths to get this to work with a Django project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is very simple:

Do NOT use the following command:

```
sass --watch app.scss:app.css
```

I spent hours trying to get this to work and then realized that all that is needed is:

```
compass watch
```

I ran the "compass watch" in the Windows 7 Ruby command shell, while in the foundation directory specific to my Django project "zurbtest", which was:

c:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/zurbtest/static/zurbstyle

"zurbstyle" was the name of the zurb foundation project I set up with the compass create command.

Note that by default, the resulting output file, app.css, gets put in:

c:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/zurbtest/static/zurbstyle/stylesheets